# Replace space with new line in vue js

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I am trying to replace the spaces between the name to new line in vuejs but I am not able to achieve it. Please help me find where I going wrong. Right now the names are showing as

```
Jack William
```

but I want it to display as

```
Jack
William
```

Below is the code.

```
<template>
  <div>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-flex xs12 sm12 md2 v-for='user in users'>
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>{{ formatUserName(user.name) }}</v-card-title>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.fetchUsers()
  },
  methods: {
    formatUserName(value) {
      debugger
      return value.replace(/\s/g, '\n')
    },
    fetchUsers() {
      this.$axios.get('/users.json')
        .then(response => {
          this.users = response.data;
        });
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It seems like that your formatUserName function is ok. Is the problem coming from css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this entirely in CSS with [`word-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) set to a high value:

1. Set a `one-word-per-line` class on the `<v-card-text>`.

   ```html
   <v-card-text class="one-word-per-line">{{ user.name }}</v-card-text>
   ```
2. Add a `style` for that class to set `word-spacing` to `100vw`.

   ```css
   .one-word-per-line {
     word-spacing: 100vw;
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/mdWYMrE)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use CSS and apply `white-space: pre;` to the content:

```
<v-card-title style="white-space: pre">{{ formatUserName(user.name) }}</v-card-title>
```